# How to get valid HTML attributes out of object htmlAttributes when attribute is " data-* "

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I would like to pass htmlAttributes as an `object` to a method like so...

```
     foo.HtmlAttributes(new { data_bind = "foo"});
```

In all the MVC HtmlHelpers I have used the underscore as a hyphen, this would output valid html `"data-bind"`

Under the hood this is what is going on as per the following questions:

[How to get values out of object HtmlAttributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315344/how-to-get-values-out-of-object-htmlattributes)

[Passing an object to HTML attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434865/asp-net-mvc-3-passing-object-to-html-attributes)

```
    public virtual void HtmlAttributes(object htmlAttributes)
    {
       this.Attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
    }
```

And then Latter this will be called:

```
    internal virtual void ApplyConfiguration(TagBuilder tag)
    {
            tag.MergeAttributes(this.Attributes);
    }
```

However this would output:

```
<div data_bind="foo"></div>
```

What can I do to output valid HTML?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to  Zabavsky...

```
public virtual void HtmlAttributes(object htmlAttributes)
{      
        this.Attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: You can use [HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.anonymousobjecttohtmlattributes(v=vs.108).aspx). It replaces underscore characters with hyphens.

Comment: Thanks, add an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HtmlHelper` class has [AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.anonymousobjecttohtmlattributes%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method, which helps to create markup that is compliant with HTML5. The method replaces underscore characters with hyphens.